# Remove the specific word "removeword" using a formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, substitution

I have this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(TRIM(split(transpose(SPLIT(Query(A2:A&","&if(MOD(row(A2:A)-row(A1),10)=0,"|",""),,9^9),"|")),",")))
```

`A2:A` is being populated by a data from the system that has the word `removeword`

QUESTION: My formula is correct. It does the job but will always have to delete that word manually. For the sake of automation, how do I automatically remove the word `removeword` using the formula above?

**Note:** the word `removeword` can be anywhere from `A2:A`

only one cell has that word every time we get the data from the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"removeword")&", "&  
 IF(MOD(ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A1), 10)=0, "|", ),,9^9), "|")), ",")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0, thanks for your suggestion. It successfully removed `removeword` (which is basically what I described). However, this still leaves a blank cell. Is it possible to let the next value adjust to the blank cell after the removal of that word?

Comment: yes, use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(A2:A&", "&
 IF(MOD(ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A1), 10)=0, "|", ""),,9^9), "|")), ","), "removeword", )), "where Col1 is not null", 0))`

Comment: Hi again, that removed the entire row where that word is in so I'll lost 1 user (which shouldn't happen). Here's the example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lKE6o0nE-dooDqbp24g8i7MCDuBXnUiHSrjRmD9rt-o/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thanks you so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Just wondering why it doesn't work when `removeword` is the first value in **A2**